# Input a String into csv file without altering

Tags: java, csv

I am working on a project where i have to read a string from excel file and write it in to a csv file along with the sequence.

Here is my code:

```
private void readExcelSheet(String inputFile){
//Method to read the input file 
    File excelSheet = new File(inputFile);             
    set1=new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    InputStream inp = null;
    try {
        inp = new FileInputStream(excelSheet);
        wb =WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        for(int sheetNo=0; sheetNo<wb.getNumberOfSheets();sheetNo++)
        { //counter5++;
            System.out.println(sheetNo);
            map1=new LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNo);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator(); 
            while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //array1=new ArrayList<String>();
                temp=row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println(temp);
                inputInto(temp);
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void inputInto(String temp1) throws IOException{
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
    out.append("\""+temp+"\"");
    out.append(",");
    out.append((countLines()+1)+"");
    System.out.println(countLines()+1);
    out.append("\n");
    out.flush();
}

public int countLines() throws IOException {
    LineNumberReader reader  = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    int cnt = 0;
    String lineRead = "";
    while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {}
    cnt = reader.getLineNumber(); 
    reader.mark(0);
    reader.reset();
    reader.close();
    return cnt;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Token token=new Token();
    token.readExcelSheet("D:/Workspace/sample.xlsx");
}
```

Here readExcelSheet is the method to read the input excel sheet
     inputInto is the method to write in to csv file
     countLines is the method to find the last line number, so as to find the sequence.

but when i try to run my code for the first time i get the sequence as '1'
and when i run it for the second time i am getting the sequence as '11' and 23 and soon.

Here is my input:

"Horizon Dental Option Plans offer the freedom to receive dental services from any dentist, while enabling members to save money and maximize benefits by choosing dentists within our large nationwide network.
Horizon Dental Option Plans offer:
• The flexibility of three benefit levels
• Lower out-of-pocket costs and higher plan benefits when using dentists who participate in the Horizon Dental Option Plan
• Access to a nationwide network of more than 136,000 participating dentists
• Discounts between 10 and 30 percent with in-network dentists
• Preventive dental services covered 100% of allowed charges
• Annual deductible options
• The option to go out-of-network; deductibles and coinsurance may apply
For more information, download the plan details.
For more information, download the plan details."

Can anyone please help me with this.
Thanks..

Comment: could you try deleting the output and running the code again? what happens then?

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
```

When you say `true`, output file is not deleted in the second call, java writes on it. Just delete `true` in that line, then it will work, i guess.

Comment: my project requires inputting of similar kind of files. so, i shouldn't create a new file every time. i want to append the existing file..

Comment: What do you want to get, what you get?

Comment: suppose there are three excel sheet.. i want these excel sheets as input to my csv file. and the o/p should be as string of        inputofexcelsheet1 1
inputofexcelsheet2 2 and so on..

Comment: You said you are getting, 1 then 11,23 and so on. What you should be your output?

Comment: the string in my excelsheet contains bulleted points,paragraph startings and soon.. may be compiler is counting those as different lines and incrementing the sequence..

Comment: you should do something like that: whenever you run the program, at the beginning delete the file at the beginning, maybe in constructor, i.e `if(file.exist()) file.delete()`. This should help you